# Error in the console after starting: intent

Tags: android, console

Hey, after i get the starting: intent line in my console 
there now is a new line:

```
[2011-02-03 15:00:34 - Versuch] ActivityManager: [1]   Killed                  am start -n vers...
```

i guess i killed something, but what did i kill and how?

my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="versuch.datenbank"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".projectshome"
                  android:label= "@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".projects"/>
        <activity android:name=".Projects_New"/>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

main activity, the one that's started first...

```
public class projectshome extends Activity {
SQLiteDatabase myDB = null; 
final static String MY_DB_NAME = "Projects-Database";
final static String MY_DB_TABLE = "projects";

static final int MENU_PROJECTS = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    onCreateDBAndDBTabled(); //DB und Tables erstellen wenn noch nicht vorhanden
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

private void onCreateDBAndDBTabled() {
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE
                + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+ 
                      "Name varchar(100),"+ 
                      "Comment varchar(128),"+ 
                      "BookingDetails varchar(255),"+ 
                      "CustomerProject integer(3),"+ 
                      "editable integer(3))"
                +";");
    }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, MENU_PROJECTS, 0, R.string.menuProjects)
        .setShortcut('1', 'f')
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
         return true;

      }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case MENU_PROJECTS:
        Intent iProjects = new Intent(this, projects.class);
        startActivity(iProjects);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Colonel Mustard in the Library with the Candlestick ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that strikes me as odd is the fact that your class name starts with a lower case letter, so you should change this in any case:

```
public class Projectshome extends Activity {
```

Comment: nice idea, but it's still dead :(

Comment: Still same output ? Paste in the new logcat output. Also is your manifest complete - or is the above an excerpt?

Comment: it is my full manifest, but now it's not dead anymore after i changed another name and the console says full success, but the app itself does not show up on my device. it is really trying to kill my mood now!